# AppleScript, Safari, bring a background tab in a background window to the front?

Tags: safari, tabs, window, applescript, focus

I try to find an existing Safari tab with a certain URL and bring it to the front. First, some code that finds the tab:

```
repeat with theWin in windows
    repeat with theTab in tabs of theWin
        if (URL of theTab) is equal to tmpURL then
            set activeTab to theTab
            set theWinID to id of theWin
        end if
    end repeat
```

If I first move the window with the tab to the front like this (which is successful):

```
    set index of (window id theWinID) to 1
```

and then activate the tab like this:

```
    set current tab of (window id theWinID) to theTab
```

I get an error message:

```
set current tab of window id 12345 to item 3 of every tab of item 2 of every window.
```

However, if the found tab is in the currently active/foreground window it works and the log looks like this:

```
set current tab of window id 12345 to item 3 of every tab of item 1 of every window
```

The only thing that is different is the `item number of every window`, 1 or 2.

What am I missing here? Window index changes depending on the order the windows are stacked but windows IS should be constant, shouldn't it?